# how to extract url from a string and save to a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am having trouble saving down urls from a string.

i have tried something like this

```
url = "https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=software%20engineer%20&l=Kerala"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
Links1 = soup.find_all("div",{"class:","pagination"})

url = [Links1.find(('a')['href'] for tag in Links1)]
WEbsite=f'https://in.indeed.com{url[0]}'
```

but its not returning full url list. I need url to navigate to next page .

Comment: you have closing `)` in wrong place - it should be before `['href']`

Comment: You have `:` in wrong place in `{"class"  :  "pagination"}`

Comment: it should be `tag.find()` instead of `Links1.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just after the "next page" or do you want all the links?

so do you want just:

`/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=10`

or are you after all of these?

```
/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=10
/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=20
/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=30
/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=40
/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=10
```

Few issues:

1. `Links1` is a list of elements. And you are then using `.find('a')` on a list, which won't work.
2. Since you want href attributes, consider using the `find('a',href=True)`

So here's how I would go about it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=software%20engineer%20&l=Kerala"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
Links1 = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"pagination"})

url = [tag.find('a',href=True)['href'] for tag in Links1]
website=f'https://in.indeed.com{url[0]}'
```

**Output:**

```
print(website)
https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=software+engineer+&l=Kerala&start=10
```

To get all those links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=software%20engineer%20&l=Kerala"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
Links1 = soup.find("div",{"class":"pagination"})

urls = [tag['href'] for tag in Links1.find_all('a',href=True)]
website=f'https://in.indeed.com{url[0]}'
```

Comment: I want all the URLS

Comment: @SeemaC to get all URLS you should use `Links1 = soup.find("div", {"class":"pagination"}).find_all('a')`. And later `urls = [tag['href'] for tag in Links1]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find()` instead of `find_all()`, then this modified url list should work:

```
Links1 = soup.find_all("div",{"class:","pagination"})
urls = [i['href'] for i in Links1.find_all('a') if 'href' in i.attrs]
```